# pass (void*) 100 as an argument

Tags: c

I just saw an example that I feel strange from a book [https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-api.pdf](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/threads-api.pdf) :

> Second, if we are just passing in a single value (e.g., a `long long int`), we don’t have to package it up as an argument ...

```
void *mythread(void *arg) {
    long long int value = (long long int) arg; 
    printf("%lld\n", value);
    return (void *) (value + 1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t p;
    long long int rvalue;
    Pthread_create(&p, NULL, mythread, (void *) 100);
    Pthread_join(p, (void **) &rvalue);
    printf("returned %lld\n", rvalue);
    return 0;
}
```

1. `arg` is a pointer, why `long long int value = (long long int) arg;` is correct? Why casting is not needed from pointer type to non-pointer type?
   Shouldn't it be: `long long int value = *((long long int*)(arg));` ?
2. Is `return (void *) (value + 1);` correct ? How is it different from the wrong practice: "return a local variable's pointer" ?

Comment: `long long int value = (long long int) arg;` is not correct. It can cause implementations defined behaviour, including raising a signal. Use `uintptr_t` to store pointers in integer types.

Comment: `return (void *) (value + 1);` can cause UB. It is possible that `value==LLONG_MAX`. Again, use `uintptr_t` to avoid that problem. It is allowed for a pointer to point past a valid object, so `+1` is ok and shouldn't cause UB nor a wrap when you use `uintptr_t`.

Comment: in Standard C this is undefined behaviour (unless `(void *)100` happens to point to a real object) but is somewhat common in unix programming anyway

Comment: If this is actually from a book then you need to get rid of that book immediately. If they can't even get the case of pthread functions straight, then you know that the code has never been tested and the book has never been proof-read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique that the book describes triggers `undefined behavior` and only works if `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(long long int)`, which is often not true (e.g.: on `32-bit x86` and `ARM32v7` platforms).

It basically is a shortcut that stores the value of the `long long` integer as if it was a pointer address (and it's therefore stored as `void*`).

I strongly suggest never to use this shortcut, and to simply pass a pointer to the `long long` variable as usual:

```c
void* mythread(void* arg) {
  long long real_arg = *((long long*) arg);
  ...
  long long* result = malloc(sizeof(long long));
  if (result == NULL) { return NULL; }
  *result = 123LL;
  return result;
}

int main(void) {
  ...
  long long value = 53LL;
  pthread_create(&p, NULL, mythread, &value);
  ...
  void* result;
  pthread_join(p, &result);
  long long* real_result = result;
  ...
  free(result);
  return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT: just a note: the dynamic memory allocation used in the previous code snippet to return the `long long` result may be avoided using other approaches. For instance, you may reuse the `arg` pointer to also store the result:

```c
void* mythread(void* arg) {
  long long* real_arg = arg;
  printf("I got: %lld\n", *real_arg); // I got: 53
  ...
  *real_arg = 123LL;
  return real_arg;
}

int main(void) {
  ...
  long long value = 53LL;
  pthread_create(&p, NULL, mythread, &value);
  ...
  void* result;
  pthread_join(p, &result);
  long long* real_result = result;
  printf("Result: %lld\n", *real_result); // Result: 123
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do the same. You dereference the pointer in `mythread()`, he doesn't do that.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Yes, of course, the code I posted is a correct alternative to what the OP's code does.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 that's the whole point of the answer. ;)

Comment: @KamilCuk On most 64-bit platforms: `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(long long) == 8`, but on many 32-bit platforms: `sizeof(void*) == 4 && sizeof(long long) == 8`.

Comment: @LucaPolito Not sure if this is what the OP wants. If you use `uintptr_t` you can correct the answer without changing the behaviour on platforms where `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(long long)`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I really don't feel like suggesting using a pointer improperly is correct (even if using `uintptr_t` is not UB). The function is supposed to receive a valid pointer, and `(uintptr_t) 53` is not one (in this context). But this is my opinion.

Comment: The second argument of the call to `pthread_join` has an incompatible type. It should have type `void **`, not `long long **`.

Comment: The `printf` in `mythread` should be printfing `*real_arg`, not `*arg`.

Comment: The edit with the cast to `(void **)` in the call to `pthread_join` only masks the error. It does not correct it. You need to pass the address of an object of type `void *`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks again, it should be correct now.

Comment: Yes, it is correct now. Since the thread is dereferencing the addresses of automatic variables in `main`, it is important that `main` never modifies those variables between the calls to `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`, and that the main thread does not exit before the created thread.

Comment: @LucaPolito Thank you for telling me that part.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it uses `void*`, a pointer to store a constant value. Pretty cool hack :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> arg is a pointer, why long long int value = (long long int) arg; is correct?
> Is return (void *) (value + 1); correct ?

It isn't. Passing integer values though the `void*` to a pthread is a common but dirty hack. This is all assuming that `void*` and the integer type used have the same size. A more correct integer type to use would be `intptr_t` which unlike `long long` is guaranteed to have the same size as a `void*`.

Apart from size, conversion between integers and pointers are implementation-defined: on some systems it will work just fine, other systems may trap in case the integer passed is interpreted as a misaligned address. Typically you'll see these kind of hacks in Linux slop code which will never get ported anywhere else, because neither x86 nor ARM will trap.

As for how to write it correctly... well, you can pass along an address to a local variable in the "thread creator" thread. The down side of this is that in case that variable goes out of scope in the "thread creator", it is no longer valid. A work-around for that is to use `static` and then make a local copy inside the thread the first thing you do:

```
long long value = ...;
pthread_create(&p, NULL, mythread, &value);

...

void *mythread(void *arg) 
{
  long long value = *(long long*)arg;
  ...
}
```

You'll still need to be careful here in case multiple threads are using that same variable though. Another option is dynamic allocation, but it is generally slower.

Overall the bottleneck in this code is the thread creation itself, so doing pre-mature optimizations like this hack to save a few instructions isn't sensible.

Comment: There is not just C but also POSIX involved. Does anyone know whether POSIX guarantees anything about pointers that would be relevant?